# Has anybody gotten PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC to work in the PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

I am passing my PayPal API call like this:

```
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=''
&CANCELURL=''
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='SALE'
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=''
&BRANDNAME=''
&NOSHIPPING=0
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=''
&LOCALECODE=US
&LOGOIMG=''
&CARTBORDERCOLOR=''
&ALLOWNOTE=0';
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=''
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=''
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=''
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=''
'&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=''
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=''
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=''
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=''
```

and obviously I am including the:

`'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC='.urlencode($desc).`

where `$desc = "Payment made from My Website";`

But it's not showing anywhere in the confirmation emails that PayPal sends. Neither in the sandbox nor in the live version.

Has anyone gotten this to work successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

It's with: `'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT='.urlencode($desc).`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include items information, this parameter will show on PayPal checkout page.